# sample size and power for adaptive regression or MARS

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, mars

I wonder if there is any SAS procedure or other software which can do sample size calculation and power analysis for adaptive regression or MARS(multivariate adaptive regression spline)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.  You would have to boostrap, but it's pretty tricky even then, see [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16100739)

Comment: Very appreciate for your help!